# How to embed images for a vector db in node js

Tags: python, node.js, vector, artificial-intelligence, embedding

I am trying to perform image similarity search and image search. for that i have already chosen a vector db (chromadb) but now im looking into embedding the images into actual vectors.

However, I just cannot figure out how to embed images as vectors? (especially in node js)

I tried it with the OpenAI Embeddings API, however its only for embedding texts, correct?

If anyone has experience with embedding images please let me know

Thanks!

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: How is it off topic if I may ask?

Comment: Did you only read the first 6 words of my comment? Or are you arguing that you are not asking for a tool recommendation?

Comment: Woah why do you have to come off rude like that?? My question is why it's problematic to ask for a tool recommendation? This platform is designed so that users can ask questions and other users can reply (Wikipedia) If you cannot help me with my question just maybe leave it as it is and move on?